# Regular Expression format meaning of [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]

Tags: regex

I am new to the regular expression format.

I just read a line of code in MVC data property, which is 
`RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")`. I spent time in reading RE descriptions on the Internet, but still can not figure out what is the meaning of the part (`''-'`) in the `RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")`.

Anyone who can give a hint on the (''-') part will be very appreciated.

Thanks. 
Yang

Comment: see the explanation at the right side in this https://regex101.com/r/jA7eF0/3

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - I don't think it is answered on that very comprehensive overview of regex problems on SO.

Comment: thanks Avinash Raj. The website is really helpful. As per to the explanation from the website, the ( ' ' -' ) seems could be replace by simple ( ' )?

Comment: yep. `['-']` means it would match all the chars which are present in-between the range `'` to `'`. A single quote only falls within this range , so it matches a single quote only.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The "Wiki" question does not address the specifics of this question. The code comes from a Microsoft tutorial, which people see as authoritative. It's probably just wrong, but people come here looking for help, and redirecting to a generic answer doesn't help.

Comment: I found this exact expression in an [old book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do) (a very well written one by the way) to validate a country name, and couldn't either make sense of the portion you asked about. I guess this is a mistake in the code transcription, two of the three quotes are likely other characters, I think it could be `.&,'`. [Asked again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48125405/774575) years later, and no useful answer was still provided. Users who close such questions on the base of being duplicates, without actually checking, don't help their peers.

Answer (score -2):

`[A-Z]` means any character between `A` and `Z` (according to their character codes)