# Meaning of ''-'\s in validation for .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I know from a tutorial that the regular expression `^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$` matches a string of letters not including whitespace. I know that `\s` means whitespace. Why when using this in validation for a field in MVC do I have to put`[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]` ?

What is the meaning of the two single quotes and the single quote round the hyphen before the \s?

Comment: That's the same string you found in the tutorial. The quotes have nothing to do with `\s`. The pattern itself does *not* return non-whitespace strings. It matches strings that start with capital letters and contain any letter, quote, dash or *space*. It will match `Aa bc'd`. Where did you find it?

Comment: Where is this tutorial? `^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$` looks to be identical to `^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$` and I am wondering if they in fact meant the two single quotes to be a double quote. `"-'` would then mean the range of characters from " to ' (which is "#$%&').

Comment: I agree with @Chris, it's probably supposed to be a double quote. From my searching, this exact (mistyped?) regex string appears in *ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and CSS* By Lee Naylor, page 70. According to the author, the regex specifies that the "first character must be an upper case letter followed by a repetition of letters and spaces."

Comment: Good sleuthwork. It also appears we've already had this question (near enough) on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173272/intention-of-regular-expression